# How can I create a directory and make a file in %appdata% path of windows in C language

Tags: c, winapi, directory, codeblocks, appdata

I successfully created a directory or folder and I also managed to create a file in that directory but how can create a directory and a file in the user's appdata local if I don't know what is their username or their user folder name? thanks!

I used codeblocks

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void main()
{
    int check;
    char* dirname = "C:/Pyromagne";

    check = mkdir(dirname);

    FILE* fp;

    fp = fopen("C:/Pyromagne/test.pyr", "w+");
    fputs("Pyromagne\n", fp);
    fputs("qwertyuiop", fp);
    fclose(fp);

    FILE* ffpp;
    char user[25];
    char pass[25];
    char uuser[25];

    ffpp = fopen("C:/Pyromagne/test.pyr", "r");

    strcpy(uuser, fgets(user, 255, (FILE*)ffpp));
    printf("%s\n", uuser);

    strcpy(uuser, fgets(user, 255, (FILE*)ffpp));
    printf("%s\n", uuser);

    fclose(ffpp);
}
```

Comment: You can try `getenv("APPDATA")`, this will give you "users/name/appdata/roaming". You should really use `SHGetKnownFolderPath` with Unicode support, specially for non-English systems. But I don't know how to do it in gcc with C.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani not that hard: `#include <Shlobj.h> PWSTR path; HRESULT hRes = SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_LocalAppData, 0, NULL, &path); if (SUCCEEDED(hRes)) { /* use path as needed... */ CoTaskMemFree(path); }` and be sure to link to `Shell32.lib`, too.

Comment: @RemyLebeau It's easy in Visual Studio, but there is something odd about MinGW. It won't even compile in c++, it compiles in c, I link to `libshell32.a` (MinGW's version) but get *"undefined reference"* error. I can run `ShellExecute` which is also shell32.lib function, which doesn't even need explicit link command.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani - Remy's code should compile fine with GCC in C (works for me at least, compiling in gcc under Windows), but you need to add libuuid.a for folderids.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani what is difference of those two, the `getenv("APPDATA")` and `SHGetKnownFolderPath`? What libraries do I need in order to use the `getenv("APPDATA")` function?

Comment: @BarmakShemirani I don't use Visual Studio for C/C++ development, I use C++Builder. My guess is MinGW's `shell32` import lib is just outdated, since `SHGetKnownFolderPath()` is fairly new compared to the old `ShellExecute()`. As for `getenv()`, it is part of the C runtime, so there is no external lib you need to link to to use it. But on Windows, it is likely just a wrapper for `GetEnvironmentVariable()` in `kernel32`. The difference being, an environment block is part of the calling process and can be tweaked per process, whereas KnownFolders are part of Windows' base configuration.

Comment: @SimonMourier I wouldn't have though of libuuid.a, it sorts out `KNOWNFOLDERID`, I still couldn't link `SHGetKnownFolderPath`. There are different versions of MinGW, I must be missing something.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, yes it appears that the library is old.

Comment: SHGetKnownFolderPath might be hidden behind a WINVER define. For older folders like appdata you might as well use SHGetFolderPath instead.

Comment: @Anders it compiles so it's not WINVER issue, it won't link.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani *it compiles so it's not WINVER issue, it won't link* Not necessarily.  If some `WINVER` value is needed to expose a macro redefining `SHGetKnownFolderPath` to either `SHGetKnownFolderPathA` or `SHGetKnownFolderPathW` (something the Windows headers often do for functions...), then `SHGetKnownFolderPath` will be left in your source code as a function call with no prototype, possibly generating a warning but perhaps successfully compiling, but then the symbol `SHGetKnownFolderPath` won't be found at link time.

Comment: @AndrewHenle `SHGetKnownFolderPath` is Unicode only, it doesn't have W/A version. The link error shows the same function name. I don't know gcc well enough, I tried `nm libshell32.a` the function doesn't seem to be listed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`SHGetKnownFolderPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetknownfolderpath) obtains the Unicode path to AppData, Documents, etc.

[`KNOWNFOLDERID`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/knownfolderid) for `"C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local"` is `FOLDERID_LocalAppData`

This function needs additional libraries for `CoTaskMemFree`, `KNOWNFOLDERID`, and `SHGetKnownFolderPath`

```
gcc file.c libole32.a libuuid.a libshell32.a
```

Using MinGW, 64-bit, gcc version 4.8.3, `SHGetKnownFolderPath` does not appear to be in `libshell32.a`. The command line `nm libshell32.a` does not list this function either. So in MinGW, we have to load this function manually as follows:

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0600
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <shlobj.h>

//add libraries for libole32.a and libuuid.a

HRESULT MySHGetKnownFolderPath
(const KNOWNFOLDERID* const id, DWORD flags, HANDLE token, PWSTR* str)
{
    typedef HRESULT(WINAPI* lpf)(const KNOWNFOLDERID* const, DWORD, HANDLE, PWSTR*);
    HMODULE lib = LoadLibraryW(L"shell32.dll");
    if (!lib) return E_FAIL; 
    lpf fnc = (lpf)GetProcAddress(lib, "SHGetKnownFolderPath");
    HRESULT result = fnc ? fnc(id, flags, token, str) : E_FAIL;
    FreeLibrary(lib);
    return result;
}

int main(void)
{
    wchar_t* temp;
    if SUCCEEDED(MySHGetKnownFolderPath(&FOLDERID_LocalAppData, 0, NULL, &temp))
    {
        wchar_t path[1024];
        swprintf(path, 1024, L"%s\\_add_new_dir", temp);
        CoTaskMemFree(temp); //free this memory as soon as possible
        wprintf(L"path: %s\n", path); //CreateDirectoryW(path, NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Additionally, you can use `getenv` or `_wgetenv` (Unicode version)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int main(void)
{
    wprintf(L"%s\n", _wgetenv(L"LOCALAPPDATA"));
    wprintf(L"%s\n", _wgetenv(L"APPDATA"));
    wprintf(L"%s\n", _wgetenv(L"USERPROFILE"));

    wchar_t buf[1024];
    swprintf(buf, 1024, L"%s\\_add_new_dir", _wgetenv(L"LOCALAPPDATA"));
    wprintf(L"buf: %s\n", buf); //CreateDirectoryW(buf, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

To add the libraries in Code::Blocks, click Menu -> Settings -> Compiler, it should bring up this window:

[image]

Then click the "Add" button, find MinGW installation folder, the libraries should be at

```
C:\My_MinGW_folder\mingw\lib\libole32.a
or
C:\My_MinGW_folder\mingw\lib32\libole32.a (for 32-bit program)
```

You can figure out which libraries you need by looking at documentation for the function. For example [`SHGetKnownFolderPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetknownfolderpath) says it needs "shell32.lib" (for Visual Studio) MinGW uses "libshell32.a" instead.

Comment: Where can I get those Libraries?

Comment: @Pyromagne see updated answer. Note that the `_wgetenv` method doesn't need additional libraries

Comment: Hi Barmak about the mingw, do I need to install it before I can use that libraries or I can just download the libraries?

Comment: what should I install? MinGW or MinGW-w64?

Comment: Can you run this program `MessageBoxW(0, L"test", 0, 0);`? or the code I posted for `_wgetenv`? If so, you have already installed GCC compiler and MinGW library, it will be in a different folder, maybe in c:\ or somewhere under c:\users\myname. For GCC, run this program: `void *p; printf("sizeof pointer: %d\n", sizeof(p));` if it prints `8`, then you are using 64-bit version. If it prints 4, you are using 32-bit version. For Windows development I would recommend Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

Under MSYS2/UCRT, I recently (like yesterday...) used [`SHGetFolderPathA()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetfolderpatha) to obtain a user's profile directory in C code.

It's worked so far in limited unit testing on a Windows Server 2016 AWS installation after being compiled with whatever GCC version comes with the latest MSYS2/UCRT installation.  (The system is currently shut down and I'm on vacation so i can't check details)

This might work in your environment:

```
char buffer[ MAX_PATH ] = { 0 };

HRESULT result = SHGetFolderPathA( NULL, CSIDL_APPDATA, NULL, 0, buffer );
if ( result != S_OK )
{
    //handle error
}
```

Somewhat off-topic, I have grown to prefer MSYS2/UCRT over the alternatives.

Comment: Ideally you should use the W function and Unicode, otherwise it might fail for profile related paths if the user has Unicode-only characters in their username...

Comment: what IDE exactly you use?